# How to remove thredded gem with all the Associated tables?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I'm using thredded ruby gem for forums but I had some issues lately with it. I would like to remove it with its associated tables, routes, and the initializer.

Is there any method to remove that directly.

Thank you.

Comment: Use migrations to remove the tables and manually remove the associated methods/files. There is no magical method that will do this for you.

Comment: Okay, thank you Mark